Upgrading an Aspire XC-1780 graphics card
I have an Acer Aspire XC-1780 and I want to install a graphics card. There are some constraints (I know I'll probably need to upgrade the PSU) the main one being space
I understand that the recommended GPUs for this model are either a GEFORCE 1030, or a GEFORCE GT 730. Can anybody confirm that this is correct or whether there are other options (assuming the power supply is available?)

There are others, with different price points.  For example, look at this review on userbenchmark

UHD Graphics 730
Intel
Bench 6%, 2,381 samples

UHD Graphics 770
Intel
Bench 8%, 15,443 samples

UHD Graphics 730
Intel
Bench 6%, 14,644 samples

GTX 1050-Ti
Nvidia  $88
Bench 29%, 946,701 samples

GTX 1650
Nvidia  $223
Bench 43%, 259,091 samples\

